# Extend templated struct with additional template parameter in C++

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

**[EXAMPLE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ca04384f0a0e0e7)**

```
template< typename T >
struct A {

};

template< typename T, typename U >
struct A : A<T> {

};


int main() {
    A<double> ad;
    A<int, int> a;
}
```

**COMPILE ERROR**

> ```
> g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
> main.cpp:9:8: error: redeclared with 2 template parameters
>  struct A : A<T> {
>         ^
> main.cpp:4:8: note: previous declaration 'template<class T> struct A' used 1 template parameter
>  struct A {
>         ^
> main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
> main.cpp:16:5: error: expected initializer before 'A'
>      A<int, int> aii;
>      ^
> ```

**Differrent** template names works fine:

```
template< typename T >
struct A {

};

template< typename T, typename U >
struct AA : A<T> {

};


int main() {
    AA<int, int> aa;
}
```

Wanna have **same** template name. It should be possible with variadic templates but I don't know how.
*Thanks for your attention*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use default parameters if you can define default:

```
template<typename T, typename U = /* default */>
struct A {

};
```

If you want to treat different amount of template parameter with different behavior, you can also use variadic templates and specialization for that:

```
template<typename...>
struct A;

template<typename T>
struct A<T> { // specialization for one parameter

};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct A<T, U> { // specialization for two parameter

};

int main() {
    A<double> ad;
    A<int, int> a;
    // A<int, int, int> a; // error, undefined
}
```

Comment: it was very easy. Thanks.